# Where is the library for 'dlsym'

Tags: linker, ubuntu-9.10

I am getting this linker error:

```
system/core/libacc/tests/main.cpp:42: error: undefined reference to 'dlsym'
```

Can you please tell me where is the library on ubuntu 9.10 which contains the library for 'dlsym'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

From the `dlsym(3)` man page:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

  ....

Link with -ldl.
```